# Como passar dados de uma tabela SQLite para diversos campos EditText

Tags: java, android, sqlite, edittext

Como pegar os dados de uma tabela e apresentá-los cada um em um `EditText`?

Estou desenvolvendo em Android. Aqui faço o `List` dos dados que preciso:

```
public List<ConfiguracoesSistema> listarConfiguracoes() {
    // List que recebe os dados que são percorridos no while
    List<Configuracao> listaConfiguracoes = new ArrayList<Configuracao>();
    // Variável para utilizar a query no Cursor
    String sql = "select * from teste";
    // Objeto que recebe os registros do Banco de Dados
    Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);

    try {
        // Percorre todos os registros do cursor
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Configuracao configuracoes = new Configuracao();
            // Carrega os atributos do Banco de Dados
            configuracoes.setCodigoSistema(cursor.getLong(0));
            configuracoes.setNomeEmpresa(cursor.getString(1));
            configuracoes.setEnderecoEmpresa(cursor.getString(2));

            // Adiciona os pedidos na Lista para ser apresentado
            listaConfiguracoes.add(configuracoes);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        // Garante o fechamento do Banco de Dados
        cursor.close();
    }

    return listarConfiguracoes();

}
```

E tenho a classe `Activity`

```
public class ConfiguracoesSistema extends Activity implements
OnItemClickListener {

    private EditText codigoSistema;
    private EditText razaoSocial;
    private EditText enderecoEmpresa;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tela_configuracoes);

        razaoSocial = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtRazaoSocial);
        enderecoEmpresa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEndereco);


    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

    }
}
```

Como pegar os dados do banco SQLite daquele `List` e passá-lo para os `EditText` de cada campo?

Comment: Qual linguagem vc está utilizando? poderia dar mais detalhes ou um trecho do código já produzido.

Comment: vc pode editar a sua pergunta e adiconar esse código, para formatar o código utilize o botão `{ }`. Aproveite e veja como o site funciona com esses links [about](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/about) e [help](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: Editei a pergunta.

Comment: Novato no site. Não tinha reparado nos botões.

Comment: não entendi qual é sua dúvida, parece que você já fez tudo, não fez?

Comment: Não. Eu não estou conseguindo fazer com que os dados do banco sejam apresentados no EditText.

Comment: onde você quer fazer isso, dentro do `onItemClick`?

Comment: Então. A ideia é a seguinte. Pegar os dados salvos da tabela de configurações e apresenta-los em EditText que ficaram fixos. Quando o usuário adm quiser alterar terá um botão.

Só quero mesmo pegar cada campo da tabela e apresentar em um EditText individual.

Comment: @user2362558, em vez de esclarecer aqui nos comentários, [edit]e a pergunta para acrescentar novas informações. Depois, é só avisar `"@fulano, editei a pergunta"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que você tem um erro no retorno do seu método `listarConfiguracoes()`, que na verdade deveria retornar a sua lista que foi preenchida.

```
return listaConfiguracoes;
```

Para apresentar os dados na sua *activity* `ConfiguracoesSistema`, é só obter sua lista e então preencher cada `EditText`, porém como é uma lista você precisa fazer uma iteração sobre os elementos desta lista.

Mas para isso, implica em você ter vários conjuntos de `EditText` e não um único como você tem em sua *activity*. Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
Configuracoes configuracoes = new Configuracoes()
List<Configuracao> listaConfiguracoes = configuracoes.listarConfiguracoes()

for (int = 0; i < listaConfiguracoes.size(); i++) {
    Configuracao config = listaConfiguracoes.get(i);
    editText.setTex(config.getNomeEmpresa());
}
```

Mas se existir somente um único conjunto de configurações (o que eu acho mais comum), você precisa reformular seu método `listarConfiguracoes()` para voltar simplesmente um objeto `Configuracao`.

---

**UPDATE**

Ok, já que o seu caso se encaixa nesta última situação que eu citei, você precisa reformular o seu método para voltar apenas um objeto `Configuracao`, faça assim:

```
public Configuracoes buscarConfiguracoes() {
    // Variável para utilizar a query no Cursor
    String sql = "select * from dj_tb_sis";
    // Objeto que recebe os registros do Banco de Dados
    Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);
    // Instância do objeto que será retornado
    Configuracao configuracao = new Configuracao();

    // Carrega os atributos do Banco de Dados
    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        configuracao.setCodigoSistema(cursor.getLong(0));
        configuracao.setNomeEmpresa(cursor.getString(1));
        configuracao.setEnderecoEmpresa(cursor.getString(2));
        configuracao.setTelefoneEmpresa(cursor.getString(3));
        configuracao.setCodigoEmpresa(cursor.getString(4));
        configuracao.setNumeroIP(cursor.getString(5));
        configuracao.setUsuarioFTP(cursor.getString(6));
        configuracao.setSenhaFTP(cursor.getString(7));
        configuracao.setPortaFTP(cursor.getString(8));
        configuracao.setCaminhoImportFTP(cursor.getString(9));
        configuracao.setCaminhoExportFTP(cursor.getString(10));
    }

    cursor.close();

    return configuracao;
}
```

E então preencher seu campos de texto na *activity*:

```
Configuracao configuracao = buscarConfiguracoes();
razaoSocial.setText(configuracao.getRazaoSocial());
```

E assim por diante.

Comment: Não sei o que estou fazendo de errado que continua dando NullPointer quando eu clico no botão que me leva para a tela com o formulário,

Comment: Tentou utilizar o debug para verificar em qual linha está dando `NullPointerException`? Ou verificar o log completo para encontrar onde está exatamente o erro? O log que você postou acima é muito pouco para identificar.

Comment: Segue o código http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=Eh8gP905

Comment: Você não iniciou a sua classe `DatabasesDAO`, pois é por ela que você precisa buscar as informações no banco. Faça `DatabasesDAO dao = new DatabasesDAO();` ou seja qual for o construtor.

Comment: Quando eu inicializo ele pede o Context. Porque essa classe DatabaseDAO extend de SQLiteOpenHelper e tem esse construtor

public DatabasesDAO(Context context) {
  super(context, DATABASE, null, VERSAO);
 }

Comment: Certo, então é só passar o `this` como parâmetro.

Comment: Ótimo. Deu certo. Só tenho mais um problema, como faço para no toString conseguir pegar os outros dados.
Quando eu coloco para os outros ele da o NullPointer.

Comment: Para dar `NullPointerException` provavelmente o que você está buscando não existe. Então você precisa examinar seu código para achar o erro. Assim não tem como saber muito bem. Pode ser o método que não existe, não conseguiu fazer o `toString`, não tem a propriedade no banco, enfim, várias possibilidades.

Comment: Eu consegui aqui. Fui dando append no toString de todas as variáveis que eu preciso..
E realmente eu tinha um campo que eu estava fazendo a chamada, só que não estava mapeado..

Comment: Ótimo! Caso tenha respondido sua pergunta, considere marcar como aceito, assim ajuda outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida sua.

Comment: Obrigado man. Ajudou demais. Daqui a pouco apareceram novas dúvidas aqui, rs.

Answer (score 1):

Bom se você ja possui os dados em uma lista e quer coloca-los nos seus EditText faça:

```
seuEditText.setText(sualista.get(numero).getSuaPropriedade().tostring));
```

Comment: Sou novato em Android. Fiquei na dúvida ainda. essa getpropriedade seria o que?

Comment: seria algo como por exemplo: listaConfiguracoes.get(0).getCodigoSistema().toString()

é uma propriedade da sua classe Configuração