# Como criar uma activity para um single?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Como eu faço para resgatar os dados do sqlite e enviar para o xml single?
Meu SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
// Getting single
Contact getSingle(int id) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_SINGLE, new String[] { KEY_ID,
KEY_NAME, KEY_DESCRICAO}, KEY_ID + "=?",
new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null)
cursor.moveToFirst();

Contact single = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));

// return single
return single;

}
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que é um/o "xml single", poderia esclarecer melhor?

Comment: Consegui o que eu precisava neste [Link][1]


  [1]: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12540/como-passar-dados-de-uma-tabela-sqlite-para-diversos-campos-edittext

Comment: Emerson, aqui não usamos [resolvido] no título. Votei para fechar sua pergunta como duplicata já que você diz que ela resolveu o problema.